# Como borrar los elementos de mi formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Hola chicos y chicas necesito una ayuda. estoy varado en un código con javascript. Lo único que yo quiero es crear una función que me permita borrar todos los campos del formulario. yo sé que sí coloco un boton input con el atributo reset este borrará todos los campos del formulario pero yo quiero crear mi propia función que limpie todos los campos de entrada.

```
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
<input type="text" placeholder="Apellido">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email">
<input type="button" value="borrar">
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
       
   </form> 
</body>
<script>
let F=document.getElementsByName("myForm")[0];
let elementos=F.elements.value;

let btn_B=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].onclick=(()=>{elementos="";});   
 </script>
```

Comment: Saludos. Usar `document.getElementById` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp por cada input (deberás ponerle el `ìd` a cada uno, en el código que compartes no lo tienen) y asi establecer el `value` con el valor que quieras.

Comment: También puedes colocar un id al form y usar `document.getElementById("id_formulario").reset();`

Comment: Excelente y me evito de escribir demasiadas líneas de código.

Answer (score 3):

- Parte de la solución ya la tienes que es recuperar en conjunto a todos los inputs de tu formulario (solo que lo haremos a través de `querySelectorAll()`)
- En lugar de por su índice indicar que elemento tendrá el click, obtenemos al botón de manera aislada y le damos un listener en su evento click
- Tienes la idea sobre que a elementos le debemos modificar su propiedad value contra una cadena vacía, pero dado que las estaremos recuperando en conjunto entonces debemos iterar ese conjunto de inputs y a la variable que en el ciclo foreach nos representa a cada uno de ellos ahora si le modificamos su propiedad value
- Al iterar la lista de nodos (en este caso los inputs) que nos ofrece `querySelectorAll()` logramos la acción de resetear sin tener que recuperar 1 por 1 y a cada uno modificarlos

Quedando así:

```html
    <form action="#" class="registrate">
      <input type="text" class="cajas">
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" class="cajas">
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" class="cajas">
      <br><br>
      <button class="reseteador">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      let contenedor = document.querySelector('.reseteador');
      let cajas      = document.querySelectorAll('.cajas');
      
      (function reasignValores () {
        contenedor.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          cajas.forEach(caja => caja.value = '');
          cajas[0].focus();
        });   
      })();
      
    </script>
```

**ENLACES DE UTILIDAD**

- [documet.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2):

Como te mencionaba en el comentario, yo lo haría de esta forma, poniendo un id al formulario y usando una función js haría el reset al formulario. Ojala sea lo que buscas. Saludos.

```js
function reset(){
document.getElementsById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" >
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
<br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Apellido">
<br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Email">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="borrar" onclick="reset()">
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```